# Where is Netbeans UI setting file?

Tags: user-interface, netbeans, setting

I want to use my UI setting from another PC, where can I find the setting file and copy it over to my 2nd PC, so I can have the same look on both PCs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under Tools->Options, there is an Export/Import button that allows you to select which options you want to preserve and creates a zip file.

To go along with what you found out, the zip file contains a config\Editor directory if you select to export those options.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it's in : C:\Users[user].netbeans\7.0\config\Editors